# How to query a mongoose database to retrieve one item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I need someone to please help me with this, so I have several blog posts of in each category in my database, but I only want to display one blog posts in each category on my index view (I'm using ejs), how do I achieve that? I'm new to node.js and mongoose. Please help a brother out. Thanks!

I have posted my app.js and index.ejs files below.

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res, next){
        output = {
        sports: [],
        fashion: [],
        food: [],
        headlines: [],
    };
        async.parallel([
            function(cb){
                Blog.find({"category": "sports"}).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function(err, sportsBlogs){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);                
                } else {
                    output.sport = sportsBlogs;
                    cb(null, sportsBlogs);
                }
                });
            },
            function(cb) {
                Blog.find({"category": "fashion"}).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function(err, fashionBlogs){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);                
                } else {
                    output.fashion = fashionBlogs;
                    cb(null, fashionBlogs);
                }
                });
            },
            function(cb) {
                Blog.find({"category": "food"}).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function(err, foodBlogs){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);                
                } else {
                    output.food = foodBlogs;
                    cb(null, foodBlogs);
                }
                });
            },

            function(cb) {
                Blog.find({"category": "headlines"}).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function(err, headlinesBlogs){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err);                
                } else {
                    output.headlines = headlinesBlogs;
                    cb(null, headlinesBlogs);
                }
                });
            }
            ], function(err, results){
            res.render("index", {
                sportsBlogs: output.sports,
                fashionBlogs: output.fashion,
                foodBlogs: output.food,
                headlinesBlogs: output.headlines
            });
        });
    });


    <% headlinesBlogs.forEach(function(blog){ %> 
        <div class="col span-2-of-3 headlines-story-container">
            <img class="headline-image" src="<%= blog.storyImage %>">        
            <p class="hs-category"><a href="/index"><%=blog.category%></a></p>        
            <h3 class="hs-title"><a href="/index"><%=blog.title%></a></h3>
            <p class="hs-story-intro"><%= blog.body.substring(0, 200) %>... <a href="/index/<%= blog._id %>">Continue Reading</a></p>        

            <div class="col span-1-of-2 hs-author-box">
                <a href="/"><img src="<%=blog.authorImage %>"></a>
            </div>

             <div class="col span-1-of-2 hs-author-text">
                <h5 class="hs-author"><a href="/index">By <%=blog.author%></a></h5>
            </div>             

        </div>
    <% }); %>
```

Comment: did you try `Blog.findOne` instead of `Blog.find` ?

Comment: @Taki - Thanks for your response. I tried using the Blog.findOne method. But I get an error when I tried to render the view. I think the problem is I can't use Blog.findOne in my app.js and then use  <% headlinesBlogs.forEach(function(blog){ %> in my index.ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

to get only one blog post, use `.findOne()` instead of `.find()` , and since it returns an `Object` instead of an `Array` of `Objects` , `.forEach()` won't work.

so replace `Blog.find()` with `Blog.findOne()` and remove the `.forEach()` lines :

this `<% headlinesBlogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>`

and the last one `<% }); %>`

and use `headLineBlogs` directly like

```
<p class="hs-category"><a href="/index"><%=headlinesBlogs.category%></a></p>
```

you should consider renaming your variables to singular and remove the `s` since it's one post.